# Tap after observable has been subscribed

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

Is there a way to add more operations to an observable that has already been subscribed? I tried the below code, which doesn't work, as the *One more tap after subscribe* part is not executed (code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-aznfoh))

```
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = timer(1000, 1000);
//transparently log values from source with 'do'
const example = source.pipe(
  take(3),
  tap(val => console.log(`BEFORE MAP: ${val}`)),
  map(val => val + 10),
  tap(val => console.log(`AFTER MAP: ${val}`))
);

//'do' does not transform values
//output: 11...12...13...14...15
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

example.pipe(
  tap(val => console.log(`One more tap after subscribe: ${val}`))
);
```

The use cas I have in mind is where for example I make an http call, and more than one service needs to be updated with the reponse of the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take this as what you ultimately want to achieve

> The use cas I have in mind is where for example I make an http call, and more than one service needs to be updated with the reponse of the call.

```
const onExampleCalled=new Subject();
// listen to example called
onExampleCalled.subscribe(console.log)
example.pipe(tap(result=>onExampleCalled.next(result)).subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you try to achieve, but the `pipe()` function does not alter the source `Observable`. It just outputs a new `Observable` that results from the old one and the operators you aplied in the `pipe()`. Therefor your last line of code is like writing

```
5;
```

Meaning you set a value as a statement. Maybe you could reassign your Observable to itself after Transformation (although I am sure, that it would look quite ugly and will be hard to understand for others and should therefor be avoided).

```
example = example.pipe(
  tap(val => console.log(`One more tap after subscribe: ${val}`))
);
```

Maybe you should go more into detail what you specific usecase is, so that we can find a cleaner solution.